# ASSERT: “m_surface” when play a video

Tags: c++, qt, video

I have two similar codes with a little difference. In the first code I play video directly by calling `play()` function in the constructor and in the second code I call play function in the button click event.

Second code plays video correctly but the first code shows me this run-time error:

[image: error]

What's the problem in the first code?

This is my first code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    mp1.setVideoOutput(&v1);
    QString foo("C:/Users/user/Desktop/files/1.mov");
   play(QUrl(foo));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::play(QUrl url)
{
    mp1.setMedia(url);
    mp1.play();
    mp1.setVolume(0);
    scene->addItem(&v1);
}
```

This is my second code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    mp1.setVideoOutput(&v1);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::play(QUrl url)
{
    mp1.setMedia(url);
    mp1.play();
    mp1.setVolume(0);
    scene->addItem(&v1);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                                     "");
    play(fileName);

}
```

more details:
 - os: windows 7 64 bit
 - compiler: mscv2013 64 bit 
 - mp1: QMediaPlayer
 - v1:QGraphicsVideoItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling `play` from within the constructor, it seems that some things didn't get fully initialized yet, which is causing the failed assert.

To test this, try adding the following function to `MainWindow` in the `slots:` section:

```
void MainWindow::playVideo()
{
    QString foo("C:/Users/user/Desktop/files/1.mov");
    play(QUrl(foo));
}
```

and in the `MainWindow` constructor do the following:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(playVideo()));
```

instead of calling `play` directly.